# using jQuery affects all my content

Tags: php, jquery

I use this code to load some links with jquery. It applies to all `<a></a>`. How do i skip some of the `<a></a>` from this script?

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var sectionID = '#'+ $(this).data("section");
  $("#content section:visible").fadeOut('normal');
  $(sectionID).fadeIn('normal');
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use jQuery `.not()` or `:not` selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve your goal.

1 . **Opt in links:**

```
<a href="#" class="special test foo">Function will execute</a>
<a href="#" class="special">Function will execute</a>
<a href="#" class="special">Function will execute</a>
<a href="#" class="bar special">Function will execute</a>
<a href="#">Function will not execute</a>
<a href="#" class="foo">Function will not execute</a>
```

JS:

```
$("a.special").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var sectionID = '#'+ $(this).data("section");
  $("#content section:visible").fadeOut('normal');
  $(sectionID).fadeIn('normal');
    });
});
```

2 . **Opt out links:**

```
<a href="#" class="noShow">Function will not execute</a>
<a href="#" class="noShow test">Function will not execute</a>
<a href="#">Function will execute</a>
<a href="#" class="bar">Function will execute</a>
```

JS:

```
$("a").not('.noShow').on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var sectionID = '#'+ $(this).data("section");
  $("#content section:visible").fadeOut('normal');
  $(sectionID).fadeIn('normal');
    });
});
```

Comment: so what about other < a > have different class such as <a class="main"> or <a class="links"> its means i have to make over than 20 js code ?!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want to say with your comment. However I just added a second way of doing it to the answer, which might help.

Comment: is it possible to add multiple class to this:  $("a.special") or can i use something like this one: $("a").not('.noShow').not('.noShow2').not('.noShow3').on("click", function(e) {

Comment: Yes, you can use `$('a.special, a.special2')` or `$('a').not('.noShow').not('.noShow2')`. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p3GzW/